# return specific properties of array element - MongoDB/ Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, meteor-publications

I have `documents` in `games` collection.Each document is responsible for holding the data that requires to run the game. Here's my document structure

```
{
    _id: 'xxx',
    players: [
            user:{} // Meteor.users object
            hand:[] //array
            scores:[]
            calls:[]
        ],
    table:[],
    status: 'some string'


}
```

Basically this is a structure of my card game(call-bridge). Now what I want for the publication is that the player will have his `hand` data in his browser( minimongo ) along with other players `user, scores, calls` fields. So the subscription that goes down to the browser will be like this.

```
{
    _id: 'xxx',
    players: [
            {
                user:{} // Meteor.users object
                hand:[] //array
                scores:[]
                calls:[]
            },
            {
                user:{} // Meteor.users object
                scores:[]
                calls:[]
            },
            //  2 more player's data, similar to 2nd player's data

        ],
    table:[],
    status: 'some string'


}
```

`players.user` object has an `_id` property which differentiates the user. and in the meteor publish method, we have access to `this.userId` which returns the userId who is requesting the data.It means I want the nested `hand` array of that user whose `_id` matches with `this.userId`. I hope this explanations help you write more accurate solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is "normalize" your collection. Instead of having hand,scores, calls in the players field in the Games collection, what you can do is create a separate collection to hold that data and use the user _id as the "Key" then only reference the user _id in the players field. For example.

Create a GameStats collection(or whichever name you want)

```
    {
_id: '2wiowew',
userId: 1,
hand:[],
scores:[],
calls:[],
}
```

Then in the Games collection

```
{
    _id: 'xxx',
    players: [userId],
    table:[],
    status: 'some string'


}
```

So if you want to get the content of the current user requesting the data

```
GameStats.find({userId: this.userId}).hand
```

**EDIT**

They do encourage denormalization in certain situations, but in the code you posted above, array is not going to work. Here is an example from the mongoDB docs.

```
{
_id: ObjectId("5099803df3f4948bd2f98391"),
name: { first: "Alan", last: "Turing" },
birth: new Date('Jun 23, 1912'),
death: new Date('Jun 07, 1954'),
contribs: [ "Turing machine", "Turing test", "Turingery" ],
views : NumberLong(1250000)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. As MongoDB encourages denormalization, i'm looking for answer than matches with my structure. :)

Answer (score 0):

To get a specific property from an array element you may write something as in the below line db.games.aggregate([{$unwind:"$players"},{$project:{"players.scores":1}}]); this gives us only the id and scores fields

Comment: i don't think aggregation would work for my case. i need to return a find cursor for meteor publish